# Regular Expression: is it possible to get numbers in optional parts by one regex

Tags: regex

I have one string, it will be like: `1A2B3C` or `2B3C` or `1A2B` or `1A3C`.

The string is comprised by serval optional parts of `number + [A|B|C]`.

It is possible to get the numbers before every character with one regex?

For example:

```
1A2B3C => (1, 2, 3)
1A3C => (1, 0, 3) There is no 'B', so gives 0 instead. 
     => Or just (1, 3) but should show that the 3 is in front of 'C'.
```

Comment: Are the letters always A, B, C? A regex `(\d)` will capture each number and you could utilize them. It won't tell you which number they applied to. If always A, B, & C, I think you could use the regex to help more.

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Python because of your tuple notation, and because that's what I feel like using.

If the only allowed letters are `A`, `B` and `C`, you can do it with an extra processing step:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:(\d+)A)(?:(\d+)B)?(?:(\d+)C)?')
match = pattern.fullmatch(some_string)
if match:
    result = tuple(int(g) for g in match.groups('0'))
else:
    raise ValueError('Bad input string')
```

Each option is surrounded by a non-capturing group `(?:...)` so the whole thing gets treated as a unit. Inside the unit, there is a capturing group `(\d+)` to capture the number, and an uncaptured character.

The method [`Matcher.groups`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups) returns a tuple of all the groups in the regex, with unmatched ones set to '0'. The generator then converts to an `int` for you. You could use `tuple(map(int, match.groups('0')))`.

You can also use a dictionary to hold the numbers, keyed by character:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:(?P<A>\d+)A)(?:(?P<B>\d+)B)?(?:(?P<C>\d+)C)?')
match = pattern.fullmatch(some_string)
if match:
    result = {k: int(v) for k, v in match.groupdict('0').items()}
else:
    raise ValueError('Bad input string')
```

[`Matcher.groupdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groupdict) is just like `groups` except that it returns a dictionary of the named groups: capture groups marked `(?P<NAME>...)`.

Finally, if you don't mind having the dictionary, you can adapt this approach to parse any number of groups with arbitrary characters:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)([A-Z])')
result = {}
while some_string:
    match = pattern.match(some_string)
    if not match:
        raise ValueError('Bad input string')
    result[match.group(2)] = int(match.group(1))
    some_string = some_string[match.end():]
```

Comment: Hi Mad, Thanks for you answer. I like the 2nd solution. It seems the 'fullmatch' is a python3 feature, I'm using python2.7, so I changed 'fullmatch' to 'match', it still works fine.